# Set attributes for all form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How can I set the attributes for all form elements that was saved in a variable? I have tried with .attr() and it's working if I use one .attr() for each input field. I want to select the form and then add all attributes in the same object.

Something like this (but this isn't working):

```
var form = $("#myForm"),
    name = $("#name"),
    age  = $("#age");

form.attr({ 
  name: { 
    type: "text", 
    required: true, 
    placeholder: "Please enter your name.", 
    maxlength: 20, 
  },
  age: {
    type: "number", 
    required: true, 
    placeholder: "Please enter your age.", 
    maxlength: 2, 
  }
});
```

How should I do to make something like above?

Comment: FYI, not sure it is relevant here (but sounds like), IDs must be unique on document context, so `$("#name")` would only return 1 or none matched element, never more

Comment: Yeah I know. `#name` is the only ID named "name" in my script.  Same for `#age`.

Comment: So i'm sorry, i still don't understand what is your issue/question. It would be so much easier to understand it if only you have provided a minimalistic sample in question itself

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can explain it in a better way. Maybe it's not possible then. :P Read under @Rory McCrossan answer, I have tried to explain there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply those objects to the elements directly, not through the `form` variable. Try this:

```
var $form = $("#myForm"),
    $name = $("#name"),
    $age  = $("#age");

$name.attr({ 
    type: "text", 
    required: true, 
    placeholder: "Please enter your name.", 
    maxlength: 20
});

$age.attr({
    type: "number", 
    required: true, 
    placeholder: "Please enter your age.", 
    maxlength: 2
});
```

Comment: I know this is working. I need to know if I can set the attribute for all in the same object?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve, as that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Looks much cleaner in the code. :) I know I can apply it to the element directly but want to know if there is some way to set all attributes in the same object.

Comment: What do you mean by `set all attributes in the same object`? That is what I'm unclear of.

Comment: @Treps You should provide concrete sample with your expected behaviour because this isn't actually makes sense

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was understandable. Can I set the attributes for all form elements in the same object. Something like I have shown in the example. Just call `.attr()` once and in there set the attribute for all my elements at the same time?

Comment: Yes you can - you just need to change the selector to select those elements. In your example though the values in each object is different...?

Comment: How should this be done, to get all at the same time? Maybe I'll split them as you shown anyway, just thought is was fun to know if it's possible.

Comment: @Treps If it was same attributes object, you could have used: `$name.add($age).attr(obj);` BUT as they are different, your question doesn't make sense (as i understand it)

Comment: @A. Wolff Hmm, doesn't they all get the same attributes then? I want to set different attributes but in the same object that is calling. Maybe I should drop this now and split them instead. :)

Comment: That doesn't make sense - how can ***the same*** object, set ***different*** attributes?

Comment: @Treps Instead of using the word `object` for eveything, better would be you use concrete sample regarding your posted sample code BECAUSE you are really confusing...

Comment: Look at that, good work, really! I didn't knew I could use a switch to get the result. Thanks a lot mate! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
name.attr ( {
    type: "text", 
    required: true, 
    placeholder: "Please enter your name.", 
    maxlength: 20
} );

age.attr ( {
    type: "number", 
    required: true, 
    placeholder: "Please enter your age.", 
    maxlength: 2
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrtibuteData = { 
  name: { 
    type: "text", 
    required: true, 
    placeholder: "Please enter your name.", 
    maxlength: 20, 
  },
  age: {
    type: "number", 
    required: true, 
    placeholder: "Please enter your age.", 
    maxlength: 2, 
  }
};  
form.data('you attribute name', arrtibuteData);
```

Comment: Won't set attributes. That's said, question is completly unclear imho